# I've got a problem with my own function. Wrong output

Tags: c, function

I want to create a function, that calculates the surface area of a circle.

```
#define pi 3,14159265

float FI (float r);



float FI (float r) {

    float x;
    x = pi * (r * r);    //pi is defined at the beginning. I cut the "head"

    return x;
}
```

`FI` is returning 3 no matter what input I give it.

Please help me. I really don't know what to do.

EDIT: changed `FI` to return `int` rather than `float`.

Comment: What does `int FI` mean in `int FI (float r)`?

Comment: You really get `3` for every input? I'd expect that if you input `1`, but if you input `2` you should get `12`.

Comment: You'll have a much easier time if you make `FI` return a `float` rather than an `int`.

Comment: FI means Flächeninhalt. It's german for surface area.

Comment: You need to show the definition of `pi`. The function doesn't always return 3 (with any sensible definition of `pi`).

Comment: @Mheldown He wasn't asking what the name `FI` means.  He was trying to nudge you toward the answer by getting you to see that you had declared it as an `int`-valued function, rather than a `float`-valued function.  Hence, what does `int FI` mean, not what does `FI` mean.

Comment: 1.You may be assigning returned value to integer variable 2.Or you may be printing wrong variable.

Comment: The comma in `pi` is the comma operator. Change it to a period `.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#define pi 3.14159265    // use a `.` here

float FI (float r);



float FI (float r) {

    float x;
    x = pi * (r * r);

    return x;
}
```

You need to change `pi` to use a `.`, not a `,` as in Europe.

Explanation for those curious:

In C, the comma is used for what's called the the "comma operator". It takes 2 expressions, `a, b`, and evaluates them from left to right, then returns the result of the right expression (`b`).

So in your case:

`x = pi * (r * r);`
expands to:
`x = 3,14159265 * (r * r);`

Which C reads as:
`(x = 3), 14159265 * (r * r);`

That is, assign 3 to `x`, then multiple 3 numbers together.

This explains why you were always getting 3.

Wikipedia will give a more in-depth explanation of the comma operator:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator

Comment: The code now works for me. Should I edit the definition of pi in my question for other people?

Comment: No, please don't change the question to a non-question.

Comment: @Mheldown Nope, people should read the question first, and then read this answer to see how to fix the problem. If you change the question, then this answer makes no sense.

Comment: @user3386109 you can make a stronger statement than that actually: Most answers don't make sense if you edit the question after they've been answered.

Comment: @CoffeeTableEspresso True, and I was going to mention templatetypedef's answer as an example of that. There were actually two problems in the code, and I'm tempted to edit the question so that both problems can be seen.

Comment: @user3386109 I think it's fine, since the major issue is was the comma operator. It does also say at the bottom of the post that it was edited to change that

Comment: @CoffeeTableEspresso I guess you're right. People can look at the [edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56709875/revisions) to see the original question.

Comment: I edited it to clean it up a bit, but that's all I think should be done

Answer (score 5):

The function `FI` that you’ve written returns an `int`. This means that whatever value is computed there will be truncated - for example, 3.14159 would be converted to 3. To fix this, change the return type to `float`.

Additionally, your definition of `pi` is, unfortunately, incorrect. You're using the European convention of having `,` separate the integer and fractional part, whereas C uses the American convention of having `.` separate the integer and fractional parts. Change your definition of `pi` to use a dot rather than a comma.

Comment: This is probably the right answer, although he says he's getting `3` for any input, not just inputs close to `1`.

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't changed anything.

Comment: Did you change both the prototype of the function and the function definition itself? Also, can you edit your question to contain the exact code you’re running, with all unneeded parts removed?

Comment: I changed both.

Comment: With the full code you've posted it looks like there's also an issue with your definition of `pi`. Can you change that and see if it fixes things?